# Possible way to flash a rom to an android device that don't connect to usb-otg or pc?

Tags: twrp, custom-roms, xiaomi

Phone **Mi 10T**, has crashed during a custom ROM flashing.
The problem is it can no longer connect to **PC** via **ADB** or **MTP**,
and also can't read any type of **USB** via **OTG** and can't also boot to **System**; can only boot to **OrangeFox** custom Recovery.
Any help or interaction I will be thankful.

Comment: In recovery mode there is usually an adb sideloading mode which allows you to install a new ROM using `adb sideload <imagename>`.

Comment: you can always connect in fastboot mode and flash another recovery that is properly adb enabled